# Ionic application requires page refresh after adding <meta> tag

Tags: javascript, html, ionic-framework, meta-tags

After adding the below meta tag, my page is not loaded on first attempt.
It requires a force refresh to load.

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

Debugged in chrome emulator.No errors found.
Help is appreciated !

Comment: For what this meta tag is for?

Comment: @locateganesh cordova-whitelist plugin .. CSP ..https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Comment: Excuse me, I assumed you added the `meta` element using Javascript - is that true?

Comment: @try-catch-finally This meta tag is added in index.html file and not added through any script means.This is an ionic mobile application.

Comment: i don't think that it is an issue of content security tag. can you post the other meta tags too

Comment: @Atula    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no, width=device-width">

Comment: well I see no error in your meta tag. Are you sure that meta tag is causing the error?

Comment: @Atula I debugged in chrome emulator but nothing is showing up .. but when refreshed the page it works fine. ANd when I remove meta tag it works fine for all the attempts

Comment: I am using the same code too but haven't got any error. I can't find any link related to that issue too. you have to figure out it on your own.

Comment: @Atula any asynchronous behaviour possible ? because half page also getting loaded sometimes in between and when refreshed works fine.This is strange

Comment: no . I am finding it smooth here.

Comment: @Atula seems might be emulator problem .. am trying with new emulator .. will update